# Else block in php code not working

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign-In</title>
</head>
<body id="body-color">
<div id="Sign-In">
<form method="POST" action="connectivity.php">
User <br><input type="text" name="user" size="40"><br>
Password <br><input type="password" name="pass" size="40"><br>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In">
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is the html code of my form which I have used for simple user login.

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');
define('DB_NAME', 'sample');
define('DB_USER','user');
define('DB_PASSWORD','passwd');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
function SignIn()
{
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
if(!empty($_POST['user']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass']))
    {
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
        echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERED WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}

?>
```

This is the php script I have used to verify a user's login. But the above php code responds correctly when I entered the correct username and password which is stored previously in database. But when I tried to enter the wrong username and password, the else part is not working. Instead it is showing a white screen. Where can I've made the mistake?

Can anyone help me in getting this problem fixed?

Answer (score 1):

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows

So check for FALSE not empty.

```
 if(($row['userName'])!==FALSE AND ($row['pass'])!==FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails when the `mysql_fetch_array` returns `false`. Simply, remove `empty` from your `if` statement, and you will check if the query returned one or more records and filled the array.